# URL valid in browser, invalid in Excel

Tags: excel, api, vba, url-routing

I do not understand why a URL is valid in any web browser but suddenly invalid when called from Excel vba.  I am trying to make calls to an API and the one in my code now should return the year 2005.  I just want to display the response to show that the url works but it will not work in Excel, however this works just fine an a browser.  Is there something I am missing here?

```
Sub testingstuff()


Dim URL As String: URL = "https://api.pentondata.com?request_type=vinserial&make=Vermeer&serialnumber=1VRY1119351005665"
Dim Http As New WinHttpRequest
Dim Resp As String


    Http.Open "GET", URL, False
    Http.Send
    Resp = Http.ResponseText
    Debug.Print Resp

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a simple error in your URL.  Add a backslash after your .com

When you paste the URL into the browser you'll notice that the browser does this for you automatically.

```
Dim URL As String: URL = "https://api.pentondata.com/?request_type=vinserial&make=Vermeer&serialnumber=1VRY1119351005665"
```